# Installing lapacke using make on Mac

Tags: macos, make

I have downloaded and unzipped lapacke-3.5.0. The installation instructions say to use `make` in order to install. It goes on to say that configurations must be set in the `make.inc` file. I am a complete beginner, and I have no clue what this means or what I need to do in order to use lapacke.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quit sure where you got that lapacke* package. the latest version of netlib lapack comes with lapacke inside. to get it installed/compiled:

1. download the latest lapack from netlib website (you need gfortran installed too)
2. unarchive
3. rename the make.inc.example to make.inc
4. if you are on mac OS X change `OPTS     = -O2 -frecursive` to `OPTS     = -O3 -frecursive -pipe`
5. make blaslib -> to get Reference BLAS librefblas.a
6. make cblaslib -> to get CBLAS libcblas.a
7. make cblas_example -> To complie CBLAS example
8. make lapacklib -> To get LAPACK liblapack.a and libtmglib.a
9. make —>  to run ALL testings
10. cd LAPACKE and make --> to get LAPACKE liblapacke.a

[source](https://github.com/Foadsf/Cmathtuts/tree/master/LAPACK)

Answer (score 1):

There is an example file of a make.inc, under the name of make.inc.example. I think you just have to copy it under the name make.inc, and then launch the installation by typing `make` in the command prompt.

You may also want to dig into the file to make some modifications according to your configuration before running `make`.

Comment: This works for Mac OS Yosemite.

Comment: Where are the *.a files on Yosemite Mac?